# Irregular polyhedron with different texture materials on each face

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a [truncated icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosidodecahedron) in three.js with different image textures on each of the different face shapes.

I've been using the source of [this Three.js example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Polyhedra.html) as the basis of my code (as I'm very new to Three.js and 3D), but I'm having trouble getting the texture material working.

This, I believe, is the important part of the code below. In this working example, I've got three solid color materials, selected based on how many vertices each face has.

```
var materials           = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ccdd }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xccff00 }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x6600ff })
];

var faceMaterial        = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

var faceGeom            = new THREE.Geometry();
    faceGeom.vertices   = vertices;

var faceIndex           = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.faces.length; i++) {
    var vertexIndexes   = data.faces[i];
    var vertexCount     = vertexIndexes.length;

    for (var j = 0; j < vertexIndexes.length - 2; j++) {
        var face        = new THREE.Face3(vertexIndexes[0], vertexIndexes[j + 1], vertexIndexes[j + 2]);

        switch (vertexCount) {
            case 4:  face.materialIndex = 0; break;
            case 6:  face.materialIndex = 1; break;
            case 10: face.materialIndex = 2; break;
        }

        faceGeom.faces[faceIndex]   = face;
        faceIndex++;
    }
}
```

And this correctly produces this:

[image: truncated icosidodecahedron]

But, when I try to change even one of the materials to an image texture, like so:

```
var materials           = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ccdd }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xccff00 }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("assets/images/lovely-texture.jpg")
    }),
];
```

. I get a bunch of strange WebGL errors, and the texture does not appear.

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext-0x7ffc6a6f3ef0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

---

I'm wondering if I'm making a simple mistake, or if the problem is in trying to apply a texture to a Face3 triangle?

Is there a better way to approach building this object and having the ability to show different textures on different faces?

Answer (score 3):

If your material has a texture, your mesh's geometry must have UVs defined.

See `SphereGeometry.js` for an example of one way to set the `THREE.Geometry` property `faceVertexUvs[ 0 ]`.

How you set your UVs is up to you. You might want to start with a simpler example, first, unitl you get the hang of it.

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks! Will look into this and report back if I get this figured out.